# How can I skip the first iteration of range-based for loops?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, vector, iteration

I would like to do something like this:

```
for (int p : colourPos[i+1])
```

How do I skip the first iteration of my `colourPos` vector?

Can I use `.begin()` and `.end()`?

Comment: `bool first = true; for (int p : colourPos) { if (first) { first = false; continue; } // ... code here }`

Comment: `first = 1;` then `if (first == 1) { first = 0; continue; }`?

Comment: maybe you would prefer to use `std::for_each` instead of a range-based for loop?

Comment: I agree with the `std::for_each` suggestion. `std::foreach(std::begin(colourPos)+1, std::end(colourPos), [](){//...});` would be cleaner.

Comment: @Paul Thanks, I don't quite understand the bit at the end, `[](){//...});` what do I use here?

Comment: @mrmike, I made a small mistake. That should be `[](int p){//...}`. You should put whatever you were going to do in the for loop where I have `//...`. `[](){}` is the c++11 syntax for lambda functions. It's just an unnamed function that you are passing to `std::for_each`. It's just an different way of saying `void doStuff(int p){//...} std::foreach(std::begin(colourPos)+1, std::end(colourPos), doStuff);`

Answer (score 26):

Since [C++20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20) you can use the range adaptor [`std::views::drop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/drop_view) from the [Ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) together with a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) for skipping the first element, as follows:

```
std::vector<int> colourPos { 1, 2, 3 };

for (int p : colourPos | std::views::drop(1)) {
    std::cout << "Pos = " << p << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> Pos = 2
> Pos = 3

[Code on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZP190rfTVD0e8t8I)

Note: I would not recommend using a solution that contains `begin()` and/or `end()`, because the idea of a range-based for loop is to get rid of iterators. If you need iterators, then I would stick with an interator-based for loop.

Answer (score 17):

[Live demo link.](http://ideone.com/2u0yCS)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T>
struct skip
{
    T& t;
    std::size_t n;
    skip(T& v, std::size_t s) : t(v), n(s) {}
    auto begin() -> decltype(std::begin(t))
    {
        return std::next(std::begin(t), n);
    }
    auto end() -> decltype(std::end(t))
    {
        return std::end(t);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    for (auto p : skip<decltype(v)>(v, 1))
    {
        std::cout << p << " ";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2 3 4
```

---

Or simpler:

[Yet another live demo link.](http://ideone.com/464Jqs)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct range_t
{
    T b, e;
    range_t(T x, T y) : b(x), e(y) {}
    T begin()
    {
        return b;
    }
    T end()
    {
        return e;
    }
};

template <typename T>
range_t<T> range(T b, T e)
{
    return range_t<T>(b, e);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    for (auto p : range(v.begin()+1, v.end()))
    {
        std::cout << p << " ";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2 3 4
```

Comment: This does not support lvalues, which limits the applications.

Answer (score 16):

Do this:

```c++
bool first = true;

for (int p : colourPos)
{
    if (first)
    { first = false; continue; }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/subspan) from C++20 onwards. This works for contiguous containers such as `std::vector`.

```
for (int p : std::span(colourPos).subspan(1)) {
  ...
}
```

This is a clean way to iterate over any index range `[x, y)`.

Comment: Unlike `| std::views::drop(1)` this only works on contiguous containers.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way using iterators.

```cpp
std::vector<int> colourPos { 1, 2, 3 };
for (auto ii = ++colourPos.begin(); ii != colourPos.end(); ii++)
{
  auto p = *ii;
  ...
}
```