# Range-based for loop of slice?

Tags: c++, for-loop

Is there any way to do a range-based for loop of part of a vector? For instance, I'd like to iterate over the first 5 elements of the vector:

```
for(auto& elem : my_vector[0:5]) {  // Syntax obviously doesn't exist
  do_stuff(elem);
}
```

I could write my own container as specified in [How to make my custom type to work with "range-based for loops"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164567/how-to-make-my-custom-type-to-work-with-range-based-for-loops) but I'm hoping that there is an easier way in boost or some related library.

C++20 appears to include "ranges", but is there anything similar before 20?

Comment: I hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936787/c11-range-looping-vector-from-the-second-element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The de facto standard (library) for this is [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) — here's how it looks:

```
for (auto& elem : ranges::view::slice(my_vector, 0, 5)) { ... }
// or
for (auto& elem : ranges::view::take(my_vector, 5)) { ... }
```

If you need range support in C++03, [Boost.Range](https://www.boost.org/libs/range/) is an alternative, though its implementation is rather rudimentary in comparison.

Comment: hm.. so this is not yet standard? This is experimental code isn't it?

Comment: No, not yet; but C++20 adds `std::span<>` which will allow this (but only for contiguous ranges like `std::vector<>`), and hopefully ranges as well (though not likely the views that are used here).